# Page margin varies alternatively in mlreportgen report

Tags: excel, matlab, pdf-generation

I am formulating a script that creates a PDF report getting data from MS Excel files.

The margins in alternate pages of the report are similar (pages 1,3,5 have same margins, pages 2,4 and 6 have same margins). 
Used the same layout for all the pages using *CurrentPageLayout*. Not sure why they are varying in orientation. Has anyone faced similar issue?

```
currentLayout=d.CurrentPageLayout
currentLayout.PageMargins.Top = '0.50in';
currentLayout.PageMargins.Header = '0.25in';
currentLayout.PageMargins.Gutter = '0.2in';
currentLayout.PageMargins.Left = '0.2in';
currentLayout.PageMargins.Right = '0.4in';
```